# Firestore: How to test export to storage using emulator?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement scheduled export from firestore to Storage using Functions on my project.
(Like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#create_a_cloud_function_and_a_job)

But before deploying the code in production, I want to test it using firestore emulator. I was wondering if it's possible because in emulator docs(https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore), it seems you are supposed to use a different node package to connect to the emulator(`firebase-admin` as opposed to `@google-cloud/firestore`).
Is there any way I can do the above test locally?

#### Edit:

For starters, I'm just trying to test the export feature without using Functions (I'd like to think about scheduling part separately) by running the script below locally.

```js
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8080';


class FirestoreFunction {
  exportAllDocuments() {
    const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient;
    const projectId = 'test-develop' // real project name
    const databaseName =
      client.databasePath(projectId, '(default)');
    console.log(databaseName)
    client.exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: "test-bucket",
      collectionIds: ['test-backup']
      })
    .then(responses => {
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${responses[0]['name']}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      throw new Error('Export operation failed');
    });
  }
}

let ff = new FirestoreFunction()
ff.exportAllDocuments()
```

Running this, I get the error message:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.

And even if I set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, I get the error:

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

My understanding is that you don't need permissions to access the local emulator. And if you set variable `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`, all the credential related settings are ignored.
Maybe I should use a service account with sufficient permissions even when you talk to the emulator?

Comment: When you try the approach in the documentation, what doesn't work? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the comment! I have updated the question to include more details.

Comment: It looks like `firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient` is trying to access the real project instead of the emulator. I've never used that client myself, but am not sure if can connect to the emulator.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there any other way I can test the export feature without actually touching the real project data?